# The Cisco VPN AuthType explained

Tags: vpn, authentication

I've been having trouble finding resources about the AuthType property which appears in many Cisco VPN configurations. In every example I can find, it's set to `AuthType=1`, but I don't know what other possible values there are, nor what the `1` actually refers to. Can someone explain this, or point me towards resources pertaining to this?

Comment: Not sure why anyone would downvote this.  This helped me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know that with the older cisco VPN concentrators:

- AuthType=1 - shared key
- AuthType=3 - RSA cert
- AuthType=5 - Mutual RSA

[See, for example, page 2-20.](http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/security/vpn_client/cisco_vpn_client/vpn_client46/administration/guide/vcA_original.pdf)

Not to be confused with the IOS auth-type for policy management.

Answer (score 1):

The AuthType will define the way the user is athenticated against the server/device.

- 1 = Pre-shared keys (default)
- 3 = Digital Certificate using an RSA signature
- 5 = Mutual authentication

Source: [Cisco PCF Files](http://johanlouwers.blogspot.com/2008/10/cisco-pcf-files.html)